# MemoryStream or other solution

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform (in C#) that encrypt and decrypt a file... it's OK,

BUT the problem is it saves the decrypted file to the hard disk, and then i could use it !
Is there any way to reuse the decrypted file without saving it in hard disk ( that the user can see the decrypted file is the problem ! )
for example can i save the file to memory (RAM) and use it as an stream !?
i have searched alot, and i found just memorystream(..).if it's the answer then how should i use it !!?
i'll appreciate any help,
and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Show us the code. It's more helpful than a description.

Comment: well why not MemoryStream? the MSDN has examples...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [CryptoStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.aspx) with MemoryStream to encrypt in memory.  From what you describe, this would seem to be the best approach.